# Outputting single row from CSV file from specific header name

Tags: ruby, csv

In ruby 3.1.2, using this CSV file:

```
make,model,color,doors,email
dodge,charger,black,4,practice1@whatever.com
ford,focus,blue,5,practice2@whatever.com
nissan,350z,black,2,practice3@whatever.com
mazda,miata,white,2,practice4@whatever.com
honda,civid,brown,4,practice5@whatever.com
corvette,stingray,red,2,practice6@whatever.com
ford,fiesta,blue,5,practice7@whatever.com
bmw,m4,black,2,practice8@whatever.com
audi,a5,blue,2,practice9@whatever.com
subaru,brz,black,2,practice10@whatever.com
lexus,rc,black,2,practice11@whatever.com
```

How would I be able to print out just one of the rows specific to the email. For example, the user enters: "`practice11@whatever.com`", and this is the output: `lexus,rc,black,2,practice11@whatever.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
csv = CSV.read('filename.csv', headers: true)
row = csv.find {|row| row['email'] == 'practice11@whatever.com'}
 => #<CSV::Row "make":"lexus" "model":"rc" "color":"black" "doors":"2" "email":"practice11@whatever.com">
```

then map the output to a model if you want.